# Decmial glitches when multiplying

Tags: javascript

Every time I do something like x186.733 it gives something like 396.328679362906736. How can I avoid?
I tried 1.3*2.68 and it gives 2 extra 0s at the end, its very annoying.

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Comment: `1.3*2.68 and it gives 2 extra 0s at the end` ... no it doesn't ... it gives `0000000000004` at the end - you must be doing something very different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Math.round() to get the nearest one.